# How to click Adobe Acrobat Menu items like ‘File’ using Java?

Tags: java

Need to compare 2 pdf files using Adobe Acrobat’s inbuilt comparator for which I will have to click File tab and so on other tabs.

How can this be implemented using Java?

Comment: Have to use a licensed tool, can’t use external libraries due to company policies.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking